# Upgrade Eclipse 3.5.2 to 3.7.x

Tags: eclipse, eclim

I am intending to use eclim , but eclim 1.7.2 requires Eclipse 3.7.x,while I have Eclipse 3.5.2.Though after I upgrading Eclipse from the "About>Check for Updates" menu,the Eclipse version is still 3.5.2.

So how can I upgrade Eclipse to make eclim work,some wiki about Eclipse's version is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest version from [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org). [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp) is the documentation for the current version.

Comment: I've download the latest version,should I override the original version or through some configurations to migrate the projects belong to orginal Eclipse

Comment: Just copy your current workspace folder to some location and point the new eclipse to use this location for workspace, it will read all projects that are in that workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add the Eclipse Indigo (3.7) update sites to your installation, and then perform an Update check.

The corresponding update sites:

- Main site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
- Platform updates: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7

It should work, but create a backup of your eclipse installation before to avoid unnecessary problems.